Powershell "New-FsrmFileScreen : 0x80070057, The parameter is incorrect."
We are using the File Server Ressource Manager on Windows Server 2019 to monitor all network shares to prevent ransomware attacks. Initially, we were using a blacklist, but now I want to switch this to a whitelist using powershell commands.
This is the command I am using to create a template (FileGroup has been created before):
$ntf_action = New-FsrmAction -Type Command -Command "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -CommandParameters "c:\admin-skripte\block-ransomware\block-ransomware.ps1 '[Source Io Owner]' '[Source File Path]' '[Server]'"

New-FsrmFileScreenTemplate -Name "testing" -IncludeGroup "Whitelist" -Notification $ntf_action

Fails with error New-FsrmFileScreenTemplate : 0x80070057, The parameter is incorrect. (or 0x80070057, Falscher Parameter. in German)

Thanks to Elmofuntz on reddit for supplying the missing bit:

Turns out that -SecurityLevel and -KillTimeout are both required
switches even though the help says they are not.

Solution is to add these to New-FsrmAction:
$ntf_action = New-FsrmAction ... -SecurityLevel LocalService -KillTimeout 12

